# How can i use scanf to plug in names and receive sentences as outputs?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I cant figure out what is wrong with my code. I want to be able to type in any of those names as the scanf function and then the words should come up that i have in the printf functions (the error occurs when i try to type in a name):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>  

int main()  
{  

    char *Name; 
    char *Carson; 
    char *Kam; 
    char *David; 
    char *Avery; 
    char *Taylor; 
    char *Brian;  

    printf("Enter a name:\n"); 
    scanf("%s",Name);  

    printf("%s Hello Carson\n", Carson); 
    printf("%s Whats up?\n?", Kam); 
    printf("%s What are you looking at me for, I dont have any gum!!\n", David); 
    printf("%s Good luck with volleyball this weekend!!\n", Avery); 
    printf("%s Unauthorized user. Please back away!\n", Taylor); 
    printf("%s Hello user.\n", Brian);

    return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
char *Name;
```

to

```
char Name[100];
```

or use `malloc` to allocate memory for `char *Name` first before reading data to it.

And it seems you didn't initialize `Carson/Kam/...` before print them out. Try to fix them too.

Comment: after doing that it produces all printf results, no matter which name i plug in. any fix for that?